# Graphic problem

Tags: nvidia, graphics, games

I've recently installed Ubuntu 17.04 on my laptop.

I have a problem with *Europa Universalis 4* - I installed it using Steam and there weren't any problems, but when I decided to play, something strange happened: in the menu I had about 2 FPS, but switching off tree rendering helped.

But there is another problem: letters, buttons etc are all in good quality, but the world map is terrible. See the screenshot below:

[image: map screenshot]

In the past I was playing this game (identical graphic settings) on Windows 8/10 on the same laptop (Sony SVF1521P6EW) with no problems.

EDIT: How to test if the game is running on GeForce or integrated card?

Comment: Do you know if you installed the nvidia proprietary drivers? Steam doesn't work with open source drivers (nouveau).

Comment: changing it to nvidias drivers didn't helped